# python read from fd directly into bytearray

Tags: python, io, python-2.7

Is there a means to read from a file *descriptor* (not an IO-like object) directly into a [bytearray](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=bytearray#bytearray)?

Right now I use a temporary `FileIO` object to mediate, something like:

```
def fd_readinto(fd, ba):
    fio = io.FileIO(fd, closefd = False)
    return fio.readinto(ba)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no function that does this, and your method is already the fastest approach.

I was going to suggest `bytearray(mmap)`, `array.fromfile`, and even a homebrew `os.read()` using `bytearray` and `memoryview`, but `FileIO.readinto` is *screaming fast*. (It makes sense that it would be because it performs only one system call.)

```
import os
import mmap, io, array
import timeit

fn = 'path-to-largeish-file'

def fd_readinto_mmap(fd, ba):
    m = mmap.mmap(fd, 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
    ba.extend(m)
    m.close()

def fd_readinto_fio(fd, ba):
    sz = os.fstat(fd).st_size
    ba2 = bytearray(sz)
    with io.FileIO(fd, closefd = False) as fio:
        fio.readinto(ba2)
    ba.extend(ba2)

def fd_readinto_array(fd, ba):
    ar = array.array('c')
    sz = os.fstat(fd).st_size
    fp = os.fdopen(fd, 'rb')
    ar.fromfile(fp, sz)
    ba.extend(ar)

def fd_readinto_mv(fd, ba):
    stat = os.fstat(fd)
    blksize = getattr(stat, 'st_blksize', 4096)
    bufsize = stat.st_size
    buf = bytearray(bufsize)
    m = memoryview(buf)
    while True:
        b = os.read(fd, blksize)
        s = len(b)
        if not s: break
        m[:s], m = b, m[s:]
    writtenbytes = buffer(buf, 0, bufsize-len(m))
    ba.extend(writtenbytes)

setup = """
from __main__ import fn, fd_readinto_mmap, fd_readinto_fio, fd_readinto_array, fd_readinto_mv
import os
openfd = lambda : os.open(fn, os.O_RDONLY)
closefd = lambda fd: os.close(fd)
"""


reps = 2
tests = {
    'fio' : "fd=openfd(); fd_readinto_fio(fd, bytearray()); closefd(fd)",
    'mmap': "fd=openfd(); fd_readinto_mmap(fd, bytearray()); closefd(fd)",
    'array': "fd=openfd(); fd_readinto_array(fd, bytearray());",
    'mv' : "fd=openfd(); fd_readinto_mv(fd, bytearray()); closefd(fd)",
}

width = max(map(len, tests))
for n,t in tests.iteritems():
    time = timeit.timeit(t, setup, number=reps)
    print ("{:%s} {}" % width).format(n, time)
```

On my system (OS X 10.14.6, Python 2.7.10), `FileIO` is the fastest option:

```
mmap  7.19839119911
array 5.72453403473
mv    0.49933886528
fio   0.299485206604
```

Comment: I hate to say this -- but your analysis is flawed. According to these results, fio is ~100,000 times faster than everything else (which caused my left eyebrow to raise quite high <grin>). I spent some time examining your code, and discovered the flaw.  According to the docs (http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.readinto), "...readinto(b) reads up to len(b) bytes..." In your example, you are passing an empty bytearray(), so it returns zero bytes. If you pre-grow the bytearray() to it's appropriate size, you'll get saner results.

Comment: You are right! I corrected the code and benchmark. It's still the fastest method though.